# Enabling opus codec in Handbrake

Tags: handbrake, ogg-opus

I'm attempting to transcode a video file using Handbrake on Ubuntu 18.04, and I'd like the output to use the Opus codec. This appears to be supported generally by Handbrake, but it is disabled for me:

[image: Opus disabled]

I have attempted to determine if packages or libraries may be missing that are causing this. I've confirmed that all of the following are installed:

- ffmpeg (confirmed that the installed version was compiled with --enable-libopus)
- libopus0
- gstreamer1.0-plugins-good
- gstreamer1.0-plugins-bad (I'm not sure how all the gstreamer plugins relate, but this one depends on libopus0)

I also confirmed that I can manually transcode the video to the desired format by directly invoking ffmpeg.

What can I do to enable the Opus option?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out that I simply needed to manually change container formats to allow Opus to be used. On the summary tab, I simply changed from MPEG-4 to Matroska.